# Python try except

Tags: python

```
try:
    #statement 1
    #statement 2
except Exception, err:
    print err
    pass
```

This may be very trivial but I never actually thought about it until now and I found myself not being able to answer the following questions:

1. Does statement 2 gets executed if an error is raised in statement 1?
2. How does Exception deal with in a case where an error is raised for both statement 1 and statement 2? Which error does it print out in the above code? Both?

Comment: A question for you that might help make it "click" in your mind:  If there was an error in statement 1, how can you guaruntee statement 2 will do the correct thing?

Comment: And you never got the idea to just try it out yourself?

Comment: @poke are you saying I could just come up with a question without trying?

Comment: @ealeon I think what he is saying is that it is a trivial thing to try out for yourself, in a somewhat sardonic way.  Just have the first statement be a raise statement and the second be a print, see if you get that print.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is "no" to both of your questions.

As soon as an error is thrown in a `try/except` block, the `try` part is immediately exited:

```
>>> try:
...     1/0
...     print 'hi'
... except ZeroDivisionError, e:
...     print 'error'
...
error
>>>
```

As you can see, the code never gets to the `print 'hi'` part, even though I made an `except` for it.

You can read more [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html).

Answer (score 9):

From Python docs:

> If an exception occurs during execution of the try clause, the rest of
> the clause is skipped. Then if its type matches the exception named
> after the except keyword, the except clause is executed, and then
> execution continues after the try statement.

So as soon as an error occurs, it skips to the exception

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 4):

Upon an exception being raised control leaves the `try` block at the point the exception is raised and is given to the appropriate `except` block.  If statement 1 throws an exception, statement 2 will not execute.

This answers your second question as well: it's not possible for the scenario you describe to happen.

Answer (score 4):

> 1) Does statement 2 gets executed if an error is raised in statement 1?

No. Exception will  be raised and catched.
As I understand python will move up the stack and looks for an exception handler in the caller

> 2) How does Exception deal with in a case where an error is raised for both statement 1 and statement 2? Which error does it print out in the above code? both?

statement 2 will not be run so no exceptions will be raised for it

any exception from the `try` block will be caught. That is why  for all `try`/`except` clauses, limit the try clause to the absolute minimum amount of code necessary. Again, this avoids masking bugs.

Answer (score 3):

> 1) Does statement 2 gets executed if an error is raised in statement
>   1?

nope, statement 2 is not executed

> 2) How does Exception deal with in a case where an error is raised for
>   both statement 1 and statement 2? Which error does it print out in the
>   above code? both?

only statement 1 has a chance to raise an error, see above,

NOTE: if you want statement 2 to execute always, you can use `finally` with the try/except