# Python Error Handling while base decoding

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to do the following :
I have read a code in `base64` via QR Code and then I converted it.

If I get an error while I do the convert, I will write a error variable to 1 and then continue without exiting the program.

I don't find a solution for me. Did anyone has an idea how I can handle it?

I tried it with the `Python Try Command` but I didn't get it working or I have done something wrong.

here is a snip of my code:

```
        secure = base64.b64decode(secure_base).decode("utf-8", "ignore")
        number = base64.b64decode(number_base).decode("utf-8", "ignore")
        start = int(base64.b64decode(start_base).decode("utf-8", "ignore"))
        end = int(base64.b64decode(end_base).decode("utf-8", "ignore"))
```

thanks a lot.

Comment: `I tried it with the Python Try Command but I didn't get it working or I have done something wrong.` Can you show what you tried here? Or, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19593198/6400614

Comment: hi i discriped it below

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `try` and `Except` in `python` in the following manner.

```
try:
    """some intelligent program here, which some times may FOOBAR"""
except Exception as e:
    error_recieved = e
    """Do whatever you want here incase of an error"""
```

Remember that the program in `try` skips to `except` just after the  line in which the error/exception occured.

Comment: i use the try command. i do the following:  
`try:  
        secure = base64.b64decode(secure_base).decode("utf-8", "ignore")  
        number = base64.b64decode(number_base).decode("utf-8", "ignore")  
        start = int(base64.b64decode(start_base).decode("utf-8", "ignore"))  
        end = int(base64.b64decode(end_base).decode("utf-8", "ignore"))  
except:  
        error = 1`  
But this did not work

Comment: What does `did not work` mean? Did the `error=1` not get set?

Comment: yes the error did not set the variable and if i use the variable later in my code like number it is empty